# Javascript View Original (Non-sourced mapped) Source Files?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, jsx, transpiler

I have a JavaScript application which uses source mapping. i.e., there are `.map` files serving for each of the `.js` files. (It's probably not relevant but specifically I transpile .jsx and ES6 to ES5 via Babel). In Chrome Dev Tools the source maps load as expected. However, sometimes, while debugging, I want to inspect the actual raw transpiled code. Is there any way to switch to viewing the transpiled code?

Comment: You could go to the devtools settings and uncheck the "Sources > Enable JavaScript source maps". Though this will need refreshing.